How to make Angular image slider skip intermediate steps when jumping between slides?
I have implemented an image slider in my Angular application, and it is working fine. However, I would like to modify its behavior when jumping directly between non-adjacent slides using the round navigation buttons below the slider.
Currently, when I move from one image to another (e.g., from the 4th image to the 2nd image), the slider shows all intermediate images as it transitions. I would like the slider to skip these intermediate steps and smoothly glide directly from the current image to the target image, displaying only the two images involved in the transition (the starting and ending images).
What is a way to implement this?
Here is a Stackblitz Demo
html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div
      class="slide"
      *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{'active': i === currentIndex, 'prev': i === (currentIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length}"
    >
      <img [src]="image" alt="Image {{ i + 1 }}" />
    </div>

    <div class="nav prev" (click)="prevSlide()">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="nav next" (click)="nextSlide()">&#10095;</div>
  </div>

  <div class="indicators">
    <span
      class="dot"
      *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{'active': i === currentIndex}"
      (click)="goToSlide(i)"
    ></span>
  </div>
</div>

css
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, left 1s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider .slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

.slider .slide.prev {
  left: -100%;
}

.slider .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slider .nav.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.slider .nav.next {
  right: 0;
}

.indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

.indicators .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.indicators .dot.active {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.indicators .dot:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

ts
export class App {
  images: string[] = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg',

    'https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/Zugpsitze_mountain.jpg?crop=0%2C176%2C3008%2C1654&wid=4000&hei=2200&scl=0.752',

    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-souvenirpixels-417074.jpg&fm=jpg',

    'https://www.wbcsd.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/Accelerating-business-along-the-road-to-a-nature-positive-future_i1140.jpg',
  ];

  currentIndex: number = 0;

  public prevSlide() {
    this.currentIndex =
      this.currentIndex === 0 ? this.images.length - 1 : this.currentIndex - 1;
  }

  public nextSlide() {
    this.currentIndex =
      this.currentIndex === this.images.length - 1 ? 0 : this.currentIndex + 1;
  }

  public goToSlide(index: number) {
    this.currentIndex = index;
  }
}


Perhaps the Angular material implementation of the stepper will help. Elements can be skipped without the element in between being displayed.
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
